# Maze generation issue with segmention fault

Tags: c++, stack, maze

I have an issue with segmention faults that I fail to solve, perhaps someone could have a look at it? More info down below.
The program is supposed to generate a "perfect" maze.

Maze.cp
http://pastebin.com/gYazVk4h

Maze.h
http://pastebin.com/cT4GddgB

main.cpp

```
#include "Maze.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <getopt.h> // includes the getopt command for input flags
#include <stdlib.h> // for EXIT_FAILURE and EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <stack>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
        Maze labyrinth;
        labyrinth.Create_maze(15, 40);
        labyrinth.Print_maze();


        return 0;
}
```

I could paste the other two files as well but I believe it's smarter to keep em on pastebin as they're quite big ?

Anyhow, I get segmention fault when I run it.
**NOTE 1**:
On Line 38 and 39, you must uncomment the while loop and comment out the for loop.
I were using the for loop for debugging.

**Note 2**:
I believe the problem lies on Line 119 - 121 but I'm not certain and I tried various kinds and can't figure out how to solve it.

**Note 3**:
I'm following the following pseudo code from Mazeworks DOT com:

```
create a CellStack (LIFO) to hold a list of cell locations 
set TotalCells = number of cells in grid 
choose a cell at random and call it CurrentCell 
set VisitedCells = 1 
while VisitedCells < TotalCells 
    find all neighbors of CurrentCell with all walls intact  
    if one or more found 
        choose one at random 
        knock down the wall between it and CurrentCell 
        push CurrentCell location on the CellStack 
        make the new cell CurrentCell 
        add 1 to VisitedCells else 
        pop the most recent cell entry off the CellStack 
        make it CurrentCell endIf 

endWhile
```

Comment: the error is clear if you use a debugger, you are crashing when accessing 16th element of Map, which is out of bound.

Comment: Like @yngum infers, use a debugger!   If you cannot debug, you cannot program.

Comment: I'm using g++ with sublime but when I compiled with my makefile through the terminal it strange enough but it wouldn't give me any more information than "Segmention fault" compared to when I used Sublime to build it, it actually gave me something more useful ;P

I've solved the problem but I've still got one small issue ..
Now my bottom and right border becomes 2 characters thick whenever the maze size is even on respective side.

I could edit my newer version if anyone is interested in seeing how I've solved it?